# Nginx + NodeJs - Limit port access to a server name

Tags: node.js, nginx

i’m new to the javascript world and im trying to publish online a small react app that i‘ve done for tests.

So, first i installed nodejs in my server that already has nginx. Then expressjs, configure it and made a nginx .conf file that uses proxy_reverse to access port 8080 (chosen for nodejs). When i access the server name of that .conf file, without the port, the page it’s shown correctly.

The problem is, if i access another server name configured in my server and add the 8080 port at the end, nginx shows me my nodejs app, even with a server name different from the one configured in proxy_reverse.

Is there any way to limit access to that specific port to one specific server name and return a error everywhere else?

My nginx conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name react.mydomain.com;


    access_log  /var/log/nginx/react.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/react.error.log error;

    location / {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:8080;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

            # Enables WS support
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

}

Thanks

Comment: `nginx` is not listening on port 8080. If you enter a URL with `:8080` you are talking directly to NodeJS. You should probably avoid exposing port 8080 to the internet - particularly if you intend to access the service via the reverse proxy.

Comment: i use reverse proxy so that i can assign a domain to a node process, without the port. is there any other way to access multiple node js process in the same machine without using format http://domain:port?

Comment: You can make another server block with a different subdomaim and proxy pass to a different port.

Comment: i already use proxy to pass a port to one subdomain. my problem is, using proxy, when i access to another subdomain and add the port, it stills access de nodejs. i understand why this happens because of @RichardSmith comment. But i dont understand how to prevent exposing the ports unless it's defined in nginx server.

Comment: What do you mean by *add the port*? Do you mean browsing to a URL like `http://subdomain.example.com:8080/`? Because allowing or disallowing access to any particular port is the job of your firewall and not `nginx`.